# C# How to use a WebBrowser as an arg for class type

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control

I am going to build a webbrowser class for C#,to use webbrowser as arg,so that next time I can call it with different webbrowser name such as "web","webbrowser1","webusing" or calling in different language,after I built it and called it,the message shows:

Non-static method requires a target.

I think the public void SaveCaptchaImage(WebBrowser webBrowser1) need to fix,but how shall I fix it?Thanks everyone,the codes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using mshtml;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

namespace myweb
    {
        public class usingweb
        {
            public void SaveCaptchaImage(WebBrowser webBrowser1)
            {
                ...
                IHTMLDocument2 doc = (IHTMLDocument2)webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument;
                ...
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to instantiate the class to use it.

```
var w = new usingweb();
w.SaveCaptchaImage(wb1);
```

Comment: Actually I want to call in 3dsmax ,I did not test in C#,but I used the same method,I found another solution just change dotclass to dotobject then it works,thanks for great help!